# returning values by ajax in input type jquery not picking up those values

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am sending data for checking weather the item exist or not if yes I am returning 1 and in else condition I am returning 0. I am using codeigniter framework for jquery ajax request and when values get return in ajax I wont be able to pick those values directly after the ajax request get completed I am wondering why I am unable to get those values which is returned . firstly the issue was that ajax was returning values with a lot of spaces so I change my technique to get the result but still I am stuck please help me out. 
here is my controller code .

```
function check_upload()
    {
        $data=array(
                    'pname'=>$this->input->post('imgdata'),
                    'current_session_id'=>$this->input->post('session_id'),
                    );
        $data=$this->cartmodel->get_count('temp_cart',$data);
        //echo '<tr><td class="cart-check">'.$data.'<td></tr>';
        echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"core\" value=\"$data\" data-value=\"$data\">";
    }
```

Here is the view jquery ajax request code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var counter=1;
       $(document).on('click',".cartoon",function(){

           //start block of adding cart values 
           var cn=$("#co").val();
           var cnc=counter++;
           var total=parseInt(cn)+parseInt(cnc);
           $("#counter").text(total);
           //end block of adding cart values

           var pic=$(this).find(".imgslct").attr('src');
           var imgdata= $(this).find(".pname").text();
           var productquantity= $(this).find('.pquan').val(); 

           var productid=$(this).find('.subcid').val(); 
           var price=$(this).find(".price").attr('data-value'); 
           var qty="1";
           var session_id="<?=$this->session->userdata('session_id');?>";
           var pid=$(".pid").val();

           if(qty=="")
           {
            alert("no quantity added");
            return false;
           }

           $.ajax({
               type:"post",
               url:"<?=base_url();?>check_upload",
               data:"session_id="+session_id+"&imgdata="+imgdata,
               success: function(data)
              {
                $(".cart-append").append(data);
              }
           });
            // problem lies here 
        var check=$(".core").attr('data-value');
           alert(check);

<!-- for inspecting the item is added or not -->          
 //$("#myElem").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"<?=base_url();?>temp_upload",
        data:"pic="+pic+"&imgdata="+imgdata+"&productquantity="+productquantity+"&productid="+productid+"&price="+price+"&qty="+qty+"&session_id="+session_id+"&pid="+pid,
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            $("#uploaded").html();
        }
        });     

           $("#newdata").append('<tr><td class="image"><img alt="IMAGE" class="img-responsive" src="'+pic+'"></td><td class="name"><a href="project.html">'+imgdata+'</a></td><td class="quantity">x&nbsp;3</td><td class="total" data-value="'+price+'">'+price+'</td><td class="remove"><img src='+pic+' alt="Remove" title="Remove"></td></tr>');
           });

    });
```

And here is the modal code .

```
function get_count($table, $where=NULL)
    {
        if(!empty($where))
        {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        $query=$this->db->get($table);
        if($query->num_rows>0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: simple, `ajax` is asynchronous and you are trying to get values of html before ajax has completed. Move alert code inside success handler

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
 $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"<?=base_url();?>check_upload",
           data:"session_id="+session_id+"&imgdata="+imgdata,
           success: function(data)
          {
            $(".cart-append").append(data);
          }
       });
        // problem lies here 
    var check=$(".core").attr('data-value');
       alert(check);
```

to

```
 $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"<?=base_url();?>check_upload",
           data:"session_id="+session_id+"&imgdata="+imgdata,
           success: function(data)
          {
            $(".cart-append").append(data);
            var check=$(".core").attr('data-value');
            alert(check);
          }
       });
```

Adding async: false to the ajax call might help you as well.

```
 $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           async: false,
           url:"<?=base_url();?>check_upload",
           data:"session_id="+session_id+"&imgdata="+imgdata,
           success: function(data)
          {
            $(".cart-append").append(data);
            var check=$(".core").attr('data-value');
            alert(check);
          }
       });
```

Comment: I have tried this technique too but its unable to get the value it says undefined I think jquery is enough fast that when the textbox get generated jquery couldn't catch that text box any how thanks